# How can I change the background color of the active button?

Tags: flutter

How can I change the background color of the active button in the bottom navigation bar?  As in the picture.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `activeIcon` property in `BottomNavigationBarItem`,

So, you can customize what you want the icon to look like when it's active

try this code:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
          activeIcon: Container(
            width: 70,
            height: 34,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
            child: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          label: '',
        ),
```

the result:

[image]

make sure to make sizes responsive.

Answer (score 0):

```
BottomNavigationBar(
 backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
 selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
 unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
 items: [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
   backgroundColor: Colors.red,
   icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
   )
  ]
)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is a classic case of RTFM. :) In this case, read the documentation that comes with each method/constructor. Modern IDEs make it easy by giving you a pop up when you hover over the name of the method/constructor.